# Export object using module.exports = new Sample vs module.exports = Sample

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose a file has a lot prototypes and function object declarations code:

```
function Sample() {
  ...
}

Sample.prototype.method1 = () => {
  ...
}

Sample.prototype.method2 = () => {
  ...
}
```

When do I need to export this main object using? Example:

```
module.exports = new Sample;

// or

module.exports = Sample;
```

I have a few questions about this:

1. What signals of the project design will let me decide to use one or the other?
2. Does have these methods any disadvantages  on using one of them (performance, prototyping inheritance)?

Can you provide a short example/s on when is it good practice to use `module.exports = new Sample` and when `module.exports = Sample`?

Comment: You do know they result in different things right? One exports an instance of Sample, the other exports the *class* - so, the "good practice" depends on the *use case*

Comment: `module.exports = new Sample` would be an instance of Sample, which is only useful if you want a singleton https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern   Most cases you want `module.exports = Sample` or `module.Sample = Sample` if you want multiple exports

Comment: FWIW singletons are generally never used and signal some kind of XY problem unless you know exactly what you're doing. The two examples are NOT equal.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether the `Sample` is ever going to be instantiated more than once. If it is going to be instantiated more than once by whatever consumes it, then you absolutely *have* to export `Sample` the class itself.

Otherwise, you could instantiate a Sample and export it, ensuring that there will only ever be one instantiated Sample object:

```
module.exports = new Sample();
```

Make sure to use those parentheses - you're invoking a constructor, after all.

But at this point, there isn't that much much point making a class at all - why not export a plain object instead?